# In Rails Devise, is it possible to allow the user to log-in without any page load/reload out-of-the-box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

In Rails Devise, is it possible to allow the user to log-in without any page load/reload out-of-the-box?

If there isn't any prepared solution in devise, I think the right way to tackle it is to change the remote content html forms so when getting a special parameter, it will send the POST by ajax instead of by using a form submit, to prevent a page load, but to allow the same effective session login. Would that be the right approach?

Comment: There is no ready solution but you can easily modify your application and Devise code to do this - https://jakub.meinlschmidt.org/2016/07/08/ruby-on-rails-devise-ajax-sign-in/

Answer (score 1):

Devise does not include out of the box ajax functionality but it is very easy to add it yourself.

#### 1. Create your own `SessionsController`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json, :html
end
```

We want the SessionsController to provide JSON responses so that we can send a email/password and get a JSON object representing the user back.

Then we need to tell devise to use this controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions' }
```

#### 2. Modify the form to send a JSON AJAX request:

`app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name),
  html: { id: "new_session_form",
    data: {
      remote: true,
      type: :json
    }
  }
  ) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

This will use [`jquery-ujs`](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to bind an event handler to the form. By using adding a `data-type` attribute we tell jquery-ujs to set the accept header so that we get a JSON response.

#### 3. Add a listener

We now want to bind a handler to when the ajax post request to `/users/sign_up` is completed.

Devise will return `201 - Created` if the credentials are valid and `401 - Unauthorized` otherwise.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/sessions.js
$(document).on('ajax:complete', '#new_session_form', function(e, xhr){
  var user;
  console.log(e, xhr);
  if (xhr.statusText === "Created") {
    user = xhr.responseJSON;
    alert('Hello ' + user.email);
  } else {
    alert('Invalid email or password!');
  }
});
```

You will not see any changes on the page (except for the alert) but it will set the user id in the session so that any subsequent requests will be authorized.

Comment: You can do the same with registrations and the other functionality in Devise. One huge bonus here is that it degrades gracefully if the javascript breaks and will just send a regular form submission.

Comment: There is also a bad tutorial that advises you to add JSON to `config.navigational_formats` - Don't do it. It breaks several parts of devise and is potentially insecure.